# How to establish connection between puppet master (public network) with puppet agent (private network)?

Tags: connection, networkx, puppet

I need to establish connectivity with the puppet master and agent where the master is in the public network and the agent in the private network.
Highly appreciate it if someone guided or give me a clue for the solution.

Comment: Just what problem do you see or anticipate?  Agents establish connections with the master, not the other way around.  At least for catalog runs.  I don't think the considerations are any different than for machines on the private network connecting to any other kind of service on the public network.  Depending on your network configuration, it might even work without any special accommodation.

Comment: @John, In my case, I have a puppet master in public IP. 
But puppet agents are in different GEO locations that are privately managed and have no public IP. I am using Foreman to manage Puppet Master. How can I establish a connection between them? Is there any network configuration issue?